# How to prove the independence between the two $\sigma$- algebras?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, independence, stochastic-integrals

In Ch 4.2 of Evans's "*An Introduction to Stochastic Differential Equations*", I have a question.

Let

- $W(\cdot)$ be a one-dimensional Brownian motion defined on some probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{U}, P)$
- $\mathcal{W}(t) := \mathcal{U}(W(s) \vert 0\le s \le t)$
- $\mathcal{W}^+(t) := \mathcal{U}(W(s) - W(t) \vert s \ge t)$

and

- $\mathcal{F}(t) := \mathcal{U}(W(s) (0 \le s \le t), X_0) $, where $X_0 $ is a random variable *independent* of $\mathcal{W}^+(0)$.

Then, I am wondering why $\mathcal{F}(t)$ is indepedent of $\mathcal{W}^+(t)$ for all $t \ge 0$. When $t= 0$, it is trivial. However, if $t > 0$, a problem arises because of $X_0$. $\mathcal{W}(t)$ and $\mathcal{W}^+(t)$ are independent since $W(t)$ is a Browinian motion, but $\mathcal{F}(t)$ is finer than $\mathcal{W}(t)$. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How is $X_0$ related to $(W_t)$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Sorry, I omitted it. $X_0 $ is a random variable independent of $\mathcal{W}^+(0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X_0$ is independant of $\mathcal{W}^+(0)$ and is independant of $\mathcal{W}^+(t)$ as a result (by inclusion, the future since the start of time contains the information of the future since a time t>0).
Then since you know $\mathcal{W}^+(t)$ and $\mathcal{W}(t)$ are independant you conclude that $\mathcal{F}(t)$ is independant of $\mathcal{W}^+(t)$ since it is generated by tribes that are independant of $\mathcal{W}^+(t)$ by the coalition lemma.

Comment: If you know W(s) for any $s > 0$, then you know W(s) - W(t) for any $s \geq t > 0$